# How to create a turbulent fluid particle simulation that is reactive to regid body simulations?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

[**Reference Video**](https://www.instagram.com/reel/C1MIwf6uZpN/?igsh=aXBqcHNvbjBucXVq)

I am not able to understand what kinda approach would be more accurate to recreate the reference video above [particle system or fluid simulation]. From what i understand a particle simulation should cut the mustard, but the movement is too fluid-like(?). Also the particles seem to interact with the shape underneath, how do we achieve that?

In  summation :

> What is the best method to get the sand flowing effect [seen in the video] such that it looks chaotic and turbulent as seen?

> How to incorporate rigid body simulations with the particle / fluid system, such that the particles/ fluid flow around it as seen in the video?

Comment: Quick question: do you have Flip fluids? Will you get paid for this work, enough to pay for flip fluids?